# Mock imgur request/response in Cypress test

Tags: javascript, angular, cypress

I am trying to stub an imgur request and response. According to the [API documentation](https://apidocs.imgur.com/?version=latest#de179b6a-3eda-4406-a8d7-1fb06c17cb9c), I can make an anonymous request as follows:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://api.imgur.com/3/image' \
--header 'Authorization: Client-ID {{clientId}}' \
--form 'image=R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7'
```

and the response is as follows (which I have created a fixture for, as `navbar-logo-image.json`)

```
{
  "data": {
    "id": "orunSTu",
    "title": null,
    "description": null,
    "datetime": 1587998106,
    "type": "image/png",
    "animated": false,
    "width": 2100,
    "height": 1709,
    "size": 138557,
    "views": 0,
    "bandwidth": 0,
    "vote": null,
    "favorite": false,
    "nsfw": null,
    "section": null,
    "account_url": null,
    "account_id": 0,
    "is_ad": false,
    "in_most_viral": false,
    "tags": [],
    "ad_type": 0,
    "ad_url": "",
    "in_gallery": false,
    "deletehash": "N9YaI4CIkq3rIar",
    "name": "",
    "link": "https://i.imgur.com/12gZbNU.png"
  },
  "success": true,
  "status": 200
}
```

My test scenario is as follows:

```
it('should allow the user to select a navbar component and replace a logo', () => {
  cy.server();
  cy.route({
    url: '/3/image',
    method: 'POST',
    response: "fixture:navbar-logo-image.json",
  }).as('imgurRequest');
  cy.getIframeBody('builder-showcase').find('[data-cy="navbar-component"]').eq(0).click();
  cy.getIframeBody('builder-showcase').find('[data-cy="navbar-logo-image"]').eq(0).click();
  cy.get('[data-cy="builder-sidebar-menu-select-image-navbar"]').eq(0).click();
  const navbarLogoImage = 'images/navbar-logo-image.png';
  cy.get('[data-cy="image-file-input"]').attachFile(navbarLogoImage);
  cy.get('[data-cy="image-alt-text"]')
    .clear()
    .type('Twitter logo image');
  cy.get('.source-image').invoke('attr', 'src')
    .then(uploadedLogoImage => {
      expect(uploadedLogoImage).to.contain('iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAACDQAAAatCAYAAAAmAogfAAAgAElEQVR4XuzdC5icdXn38');
    });
  cy.get('[data-cy=image-select-save]').click();
});
```

The api call is triggered at this line `cy.get('[data-cy=image-select-save]').click();`. I want to intercept it and make the post to a dummy API, and then provide a dummy response. How do I go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your parameters in [`cy.request()`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/request.html#Syntax) are correct, you are already set up to intercept the call and mocking the response to your json fixture. You can then use [`cy.wait()`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/wait.html#Syntax) to get the http object containing the request and the response:

```
cy.get('[data-cy=image-select-save]').click();
cy.wait('@imgurRequest').then(xhr => {
    // do something with the xhr object
});
```

Make sure your request is not of type `fetch` as cypress cannot yet catch `fetch` requests. Also, I recommend using a glob pattern in your url parameter in `cy.request()` like `url: '*/3/image'`